# How can I add different ticks on both sides of color bar?

Tags: plotting, legending

```
BarLegend[{{Blue, White, Red}, {0, 4}}, 
 Ticks -> {{0, "0"}, {2, "1e-2"}, {4, "2e-2"}}, 
 LegendLayout -> "Column", Charting`TickSide -> Right]
```

[image]

How can I add different ticks on the left side to get something like this

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can process the box expressions to add the desired ticks on the left frame:

```
ClearAll[addLeftFrameTicks]
addLeftFrameTicks[ticks_] := RawBoxes @ Replace[ToBoxes @ #, 
  GraphicsBox[{___, _RasterBox, ___}, ___] -> ToBoxes @ 
   Show[First @ Cases[ToBoxes @ #, 
       g : GraphicsBox[{___, _RasterBox, ___}, ___] :> ToExpression[g], All] & /@ 
    {#, # /. r__Rule :> {Ticks -> ticks, Charting`TickSide -> Left, r}}], All] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
leftticks = {{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"}};

addLeftFrameTicks[leftticks] @
 BarLegend[{{Blue, White, Red}, {0, 4}}, 
  LegendLabel -> Style["legend", 20], 
  Ticks -> {{0, "0"}, {2, "1e-2"}, {4, "2e-2"}}, 
  LabelStyle -> 14, 
  LegendFunction -> Panel]
```

[image]

Add the options `LegendLayout -> "Row"` and `LegendMarkerSize -> {400, 100}` to `BarLegend[...]` to get

[image]